# Debug program in eclipse with a newly built compiler

Tags: gcc, debugging, c++, eclipse

I recently tried to build the new version of GCC (4.8.1) on Ubuntu 12.04. I managed to build everything correctly, it passed the tests and I installed the new compiler.

I can build programs with the new compiler. I can run them. However, as soon as I try to debug them in eclipse it does not work. It gives me the following error message:

```
No source available for "main() at 0x8048693"
```

Is there something other than GCC that I should update to be able to debug?

Edit:

Here is the "program" I am trying to debug and how I compile it.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compilation command:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
```

Comment: Did you ask the compiler to generate debug information?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes I did, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. After installing gdb 7.6.1, I can debug by using eclipse.